# One Page Website, with jump links, but hide, display:none all other content except jump link clicked

Tags: seo, url, jquery

I'm wondering how this website design/structure will work for SEO. I have example.com that I'm building. The only actual URL for the website is example.com. However, it will appear to the user that their is 8 different pages.

For example. There will be example.com, example.com/#about, example.com/#contact, example.com/#services, etc.

I'm using jquery to hide all the other 7 "pages" and only show the link that is clicked. So if a user goes to example.com, it will hide all the 7 other "pages" and only show the example.com.

If the user then clicks on the link example.com/#about, it will hide example.com content, and keep all the other pages content hidden, but then only show example.com/#about content.

So everything on the website stays the same, the only thing that changes is the "content" div when they click on a menu link.

I notice that this is VERY good for user experience in that it loads the whole website code when they first come to the website, so when they click between "pages" it is instant.

I'm interested in getting answers to why this is a bad idea for like SEO? or any other reasons? Anyone else ever use this kind of setup? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not using display:none in css stylesheet. I'm using jquery .hide() , .show() functions.. I also need to know how a page that is like example.com/#about , with the "#" meaning the same page is read by search engines. Do they just view that as the same page, right? Thanks

Comment: I was getting ready to answer this, but unfortunately it was closed as a duplicate because "display:none" was in the title :-(  I've used .hide() & show() functions for anchor links and can elaborate on the pluses and minuses of doing this regarding SEO and PageRank. I'd suggest asking another question with a reworded title.

Comment: not sure why they so strict here, it's like one new question an hour here. I feel like I'm back in Sister Marie's class again. Bad, Bad boy I am for asking a question. I tried to repost dan but it won't let me b.c it's too similar. Ill ask somewhere else.

Comment: :-) Try a title like, "SEO for single page website with JavaScript anchor links that hide content". I've got a fair bit of information for you.

Comment: i tried changing the title, but the post content was too similiar it said... i'll make a new shortened question, i appreciate all the help

Comment: No problem. I think it's an informative question because JS and AJAX are always questionable in regards to SEO.